# A basic inequality of normal pdf and cdf

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

$\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the pdf and cdf of the standard normal variable, respectively. Then $\forall a<0$, is it true that

$\Phi\left(a\right) \leq \phi\left(a\right)$?

Comment: No. Note that $\phi(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} < \frac{1}{2} = \Phi(0)$, so by continuity we will have $\phi(a) < \Phi(a)$ for $a$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029253/532409

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439279/exponential-bound-for-tail-of-standard-normal-distributed-random-variable .